# How do I use a custom theme in a module?

Tags: theming

As I know Drupal 8 removed `theme()`, which is still present in Drupal 7. There  is function `hook_theme()` to call and render the theme in a module.

Can anyone help with some of the examples? How do I use a custom theme in my custom module?

Comment: This sounds like a misconception... You cannot use a theme in your module. Your module can expose a theme hook (and often provide a default template file) for one or more page elements. The active theme can then override this default with its own version of the template file. As far as I know you cannot instruct your module to load elements from a certain theme.

Comment: If you are asking how a module can set a theme used for some pages, that is a question. If you are asking how to theme a page of your custom module, that is a different question. Otherwise, see @Neograph734 comment.

Comment: The keywords here are _theming a page_ which is different from _using a theme for a specific page_. Drupal can do both; you need to tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to add own template using theme function in drupal8. For example, we use theme function in Drupal7 (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7.x) and declare the template file path using hook_theme. Similarly, I wanted in Drupal8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy. You just need use `'#theme'` element in your render array.

For example:

**Drupal 7** has both way:

```
// Render array.
$build['cars_list'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Cars List'),
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => array('Mercedes', 'BMB'),
);
// Ready HTML.
$build['cars_list'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => array('Mercedes', 'BMB')));
```

**Drupal 8** has only one way:

```
// Use render array.
$build['cars_list'] = [
  '#title' => t('Cars List'),
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => ['Mercedes', 'BMB'],
];
```

Actuality you may create a custom theme via hook_theme() and use it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Bit confused with theme builder.